# Error in scikit learn TfidfVectorizer when using the parameter stop_words

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am new to scikit learn. I am trying to do tfidf vectorization to fit on a 1*M numpy.array i.e tot_data (in the code below), consisting of English sentences. 
Here 'words' is a  numpy.array (1*173), containing list of stop words. 
I need to define the parameter stop_words explicitly. 
The code is running fine if I don't use the parameter stop_words explicitly, but the line below shows error.

word = numpy.array(['a','about',...])

```
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=.95,stop_words=word).fit(tot_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1203, in fit
    X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 780, in fit_transform
    vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 710, in _count_vocab
    analyze = self.build_analyzer()
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 225, in build_analyzer
    stop_words = self.get_stop_words()
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 208, in get_stop_words
    return _check_stop_list(self.stop_words)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 85, in _check_stop_list
    if stop == "english":
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reason:** The reason for the error is the fact that numpy array propagates comparaison to elements:

```
>>> word == 'english'
array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

and `if` statement can't convert resulting array to boolean:

```
>>> if word == 'english': pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**Solution:** Convert words to ordinary list: `words = list(words)`.

**Demo:**

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> word = np.array(['one','two','three'])
>>> tot_data = np.array(['one two three', 'who do I see', 'I see two girls'])
>>> v = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=.95,stop_words=list(word))
>>> v.fit(tot_data)
TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', binary=False, charset=None,
   ...
        tokenizer=None, use_idf=True, vocabulary=None)
```

Comment: @amitbisai You're welcome! *Standard disclaimer:* if you found question useful, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).